Reconciling the Bible with the LDS 1st Article of Faith and select quotes about God from the Book of Mormon
The LDS Church believes in more than one God. This is brought out in my first two statements below. Yet the Book of Mormon contradicts these statements (see quotes below).
From an official LDS page titled Do Members of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints Believe in the Trinity?

Three distinct beings
The Church’s first Article of Faith states, “We believe in God, the Eternal Father, and in His Son, Jesus Christ, and in the Holy Ghost.” We believe They are three distinct personages, not one singular being. We call Them the Godhead.

By definition this would be considered "Polytheism."
They further go on to say:

Like many Christians, we believe in God the Father, His Son Jesus Christ, and the Holy Spirit. However, we don't believe in the traditional concept of the Trinity. We believe that the Father, the Son, and the Holy Ghost are three separate beings who are one in purpose.

This statement, as well, is, by definition, "Polytheism."
How do Mormons reconcile the above 2 statements from the following quotes from the Book of Mormon?
Alma 11:26-35:

26 And Zeezrom said unto him: Thou sayest there is a true and living God?
27 And Amulek said: Yea, there is a true and living God.
28 Now Zeezrom said: Is there more than one God?
29 And he answered, No.
30 Now Zeezrom said unto him again: How knowest thou these things?
31 And he said: An angel hath made them known unto me.
32 And Zeezrom said again: Who is he that shall come? Is it the Son of God?
33 And he said unto him, Yea.
34 And Zeezrom said again: Shall he save his people ain their sins? And Amulek answered and said unto him: I say unto you he shall not, for it is impossible for him to deny his word.
35 Now Zeezrom said unto the people: See that ye remember these things; for he said there is but one God; yet he saith that the Son of God shall come, but he shall not save his people—as though he had authority to command God.

And Alma 11:38-39:

38 Now Zeezrom saith again unto him: Is the Son of God the very Eternal Father?
39 And Amulek said unto him: Yea, he is the very Eternal Father of heaven and of earth, and all things which in them are; he is the beginning and the end, the first and the last;

Then there is Ether 3:14:

14 Behold, I am he who was prepared from the foundation of the world to redeem my people. Behold, I am Jesus Christ. I am the Father and the Son. In me shall all mankind have life, and that eternally, even they who shall believe on my name; and they shall become my sons and my daughters.

So how is it that the BoM teaches that Jesus Christ is actually God the Father, and at the same time the Son? This in view of the opening statements? Also, how is it that Amulek says Jesus will not save people from their sins when the Bible clearly teaches Jesus Christ is our Savior?
All of this contradicts the Bible big time! Are these examples of why Smith declared that the BoM is another testament of the Bible and the Bible needed restoring?

@LukeHill I'm feeling generous today, and I cleaned it up for Mr. Bond (although I agree that he should be the one who does this).  But I didn't touch the last 2 paragraphs.

@MrBond, note that Amulek didn't say that Jesus will not save people "from their sins" – he said that people won't be saved "in their sins." Amulek elaborates on this in verses 37 and 40 of the same chapter.


All of this contradicts the Bible big time!

On the contrary; the LDS understanding of the Godhead is the only depiction that does not contradict the plain text of the Bible.
In Genesis 1:1, literally the very beginning of the Bible, the Hebrew word translated "God" is Elohim, which is a plural word.  Embarrassed theologians both Jewish and Christian have been trying to hand-wave this away for centuries with one linguistic trick or another, rather than simply accepting that the words mean what they say: the Creation was accomplished by multiple divine beings, the Father and the Son.  (Incidentally, the same word Elohim is translated as "gods" in Genesis 3:5.)
In Genesis 11: 5-8, we see God's response to the Tower of Babel:

5 And the Lord came down to see the city and the tower, which the
children of men builded.
6 And the Lord said, Behold, the people is one, and they have all one
language; and this they begin to do: and now nothing will be
restrained from them, which they have imagined to do.
7 Go to, let us go down, and there confound their language, that they
may not understand one another's speech.
8 So the Lord scattered them abroad from thence upon the face of all
the earth: and they left off to build the city.

Who is the "us" in verse 7, when verses 6 and 8 say that the only entity speaking and acting here is God?
In Matthew chapter 3, Jesus goes to John to be baptized, and when he comes up out of the water, "he saw the Spirit of God descending like a dove, and lighting upon him: And lo a voice from heaven, saying, This is my beloved Son, in whom I am well pleased."  So we see three distinct divine beings, in three different locations, doing three different things: the Father, up in heaven, voicing his approval, the Son, in the water, being baptized, and the Holy Ghost, descending from heaven upon Jesus "like a dove".
In John 17, Jesus prays to the Father on behalf of his disciples, and in three different places, he asks some version of "that they might be one, as we are one."  It is absurd to think that he is asking for the Father to merge the disciples into an incomprehensible composite being, but that is the way Trinitarianism understands the Father and the Son (and the Holy Ghost) being one.  Clearly something is out of alignment here!
In Luke 22, as Jesus is praying in the Garden of Gethsemane, he pleads, "Father, if thou be willing, remove this cup from me: nevertheless not my will, but thine, be done."  So not only is he a distinct being from the Father, he has his own will, which can be in opposition to that of the Father.  But being without sin in all things, he puts aside his own will where it conflicts with that of the Father.
And again in Acts chapter 7, when an angry mob is about to murder Stephen, he gives as his final testimony an account of a vision he is receiving, where "I see the heavens opened, and the Son of man standing on the right hand of God," once again describing Jesus, even post-resurrection, as a distinct being from the Father.
As for the statements from the Book of Alma, it's important to read them in context.  This was a people who, at that time, was under the Law of Moses.  They had a very limited understanding of the broader principles of the Gospel, by design, because God had taken the fulness away from the Israelites.  (Quite possibly to keep them from making exactly the same sorts of errors being made in this question, like conflating a single Godhead with multiple distinct but united personages with a polytheistic system such as their enemies favored, in which each different god was "god of whatever" and they were constantly working at cross purposes to one another.)
Modern revelation tells us that Jesus "is the Only Begotten of the Father [and] by him, and through him, and of him, the worlds are and were created," (D&C 70:23-24) which is fully in agreement with the quoted passages from Alma 11.  Jesus Christ is the "Father of heaven and of earth, and all things which are in them are," because by him and through him and of him, all things in heaven and earth were created.  The design was the Father's, but the work of creation was carried out by the Son.

What's LDS reaction to Michael Heiser's interpretation of "us" in the Genesis verses you mentioned as God and the members of his divine council (rather than members of the Trinity)?  Michael Heiser holds the orthodox doctrine of the Trinity.  He also has an article Heiser, Mormonism, and the Divine Council of Psalm 82.

@Mason. You said, "the LDS understanding of the Godhead is the only depiction that does not contradict the plain text of the Bible. Yes it does, big time. Godhead is defined as "deity." My last paragraph in my thread states: "We believe that the Father, the Son, and the Holy Ghost are three separate beings who are one in purpose." The Bible does not teach the Godhead are three separate beings. Three beings of God is polytheism. The Bible teaches there is only one God who chose to manifest Himself as three "distinct" persons, not three separate beings of the one God. Read Deuteronomy 6:4.

@Mr.Bond So you completely ignore all the references I pointed out that clearly establish this position, including John 17 which is completely and utterly fatal to the doctrine of Trinitarianism, and respond with a bunch of ipse dixit and name-dropping Deuteronomy 6:4, completely out of context even after I provided the proper context in my answer.  Typical.

At the time of Alma, Jehovah had not yet been born, crucified, resurrected, or exalted a God
Alma chapter 11 is believed to have taken place nearly 100 years before the birth of Jesus Christ. Having not yet been exalted by the Father, there was indeed only one living God at that time — our Heavenly Father.1 Subsequent to the resurrection and ascension of Jesus Christ, LDS theology believes He was exalted in the Celestial Kingdom, becoming a second God.
The Church further explains the following:

The Holy Ghost is also a God and is variously called the Holy Spirit, the Spirit, the Spirit of God, etc. (Source)

The godhood of the Holy Ghost is something I must touch on, but don't have the time to properly research or cite. He is revered as a member of the godhead and is therefore called a God, but it is dogma that He has not yet obtained his mortal body nor become exalted. In His service in the Godhead, He holds power and has keys, and therefore we honor Him with the title. Elder Dallin H. Oaks quotes Joseph Smith as saying:

Any person that had seen the heavens opened knows that there are three personages in the heavens who hold the keys of power, and one presides over all. …
These personages … are called God the first, the Creator; God the second, the Redeemer; and God the third, the Witness or Testator.
[It is] the province of the Father to preside as the Chief or President, Jesus as the Mediator, and the Holy Ghost as the Testator or Witness. (Source)

One in person or one in purpose?
Next, you ask about Amulek's response that Jesus Christ is "the very Eternal Father of heaven and of earth." From the Church's website we also learn:

Jesus works under the direction of the Father and is in complete harmony with Him. All mankind are His brethren and sisters, He being the eldest of the spirit children of Elohim. Many of the things that the scripture says were done by God were actually done by the Lord (Jesus). Thus the scripture says that “God created the heaven and the earth” (Gen. 1:1), but we know that it was actually the Lord (Jesus) who was the creator (John 1:3, 10), or as Paul said, God created all things by Christ Jesus (Eph. 3:9). (Source)

Therefore, Amulek wasn't wrong as Jesus Christ was the creator and, therefore, the father of this Earth. But to really deal with this issue, we need to introduce the basic problem.
Here's the basic problem...
The purpose of this Stack is to help people understand one another. If you don't want to believe what The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints believes, that's your prerogative. But this is our belief:
Joseph Smith saw two individuals standing above him in what we honor as the Sacred Grove: our Heavenly Father and His Son, Jesus Christ. (Source, see also D&C 130:22-23) If in your desire to better understand us you accept that we believe that the Father and the Son (and the Holy Ghost) are distinct individuals, then any reference in Scripture suggesting that any two are but a single individual (e.g., John 17:22) must, of necessity, refer to another relationship, which we believe is "one in purpose."
This concept is, also of necessity, supported Biblically.

That they all may be one; as thou, Father, art in me, and I in thee, that they also may be one in us: that the world may believe that thou hast sent me.
And the glory which thou gavest me I have given them; that they may be one, even as we are one... (John 17:22-23, emphasis mine)

No one believes the ancient apostles were but one individual manifest as twelve. And yet if we assert that the Biblical references stating that Jesus and our Heavenly Father "are one" must be interpreted literally as "one in body manifest as three," then we're stuck explaining how that isn't true when applied to the apostles. On the other hand, if all such references (based on Joseph Smith's teachings) are interpreted as "one in purpose," then all the verses fall together neatly.
 "This statement, as well, is, by definition, 'Polytheism.'"
Yup. We're polytheistic. We've never denied it.

And again, verily I say unto you, if a man marry a wife by my word, which is my law, and by the new and everlasting covenant, and it is sealed unto them by the Holy Spirit of promise, by him who is anointed, unto whom I have appointed this power and the keys of this priesthood; and it shall be said unto them—Ye shall come forth in the first resurrection; and if it be after the first resurrection, in the next resurrection; and shall inherit thrones, kingdoms, principalities, and powers, dominions, all heights and depths—then shall it be written in the Lamb’s Book of Life, that he shall commit no murder whereby to shed innocent blood, and if ye abide in my covenant, and commit no murder whereby to shed innocent blood, it shall be done unto them in all things whatsoever my servant hath put upon them, in time, and through all eternity; and shall be of full force when they are out of the world; and they shall pass by the angels, and the gods, which are set there, to their exaltation and glory in all things, as hath been sealed upon their heads, which glory shall be a fulness and a continuation of the seeds forever and ever.
Then shall they be gods, because they have no end; therefore shall they be from everlasting to everlasting, because they continue; then shall they be above all, because all things are subject unto them. Then shall they be gods, because they have all power, and the angels are subject unto them. (D&C 132:19-20, emphasis mine)

We believe everyone has the potential to become like our Heavenly Father and our Brother, Jesus — to become Gods. We are most certainly polytheistic. It kinda confuses us that people want to badly to be perceived as monotheistic:

And I, the Lord God, spake unto Moses, saying: That Satan, whom thou hast commanded in the name of mine Only Begotten, is the same which was from the beginning, and he came before me, saying—Behold, here am I, send me, I will be thy son, and I will redeem all mankind, that one soul shall not be lost, and surely I will do it; wherefore give me thine honor. (Moses 4:1, emphasis mine)

From our point of view, monotheism is Satan's effort to draw people away from our Heavenly Father and His Beloved Son, Jesus. But that's just us.
Will Jesus save us?
Of course He will — if we repent. You misread those verses.

Shall he save his people in their sins?

Jesus won't save anyone "in their sins." He saves us from sin through repentance. Choose not to repent and be redeemed through the atonement of Jesus Christ, live with the fact you won't be saved. Paul clearly taught this in the Bible:

For if we sin wilfully after that we have received the knowledge of the truth, there remaineth no more sacrifice for sins, but a certain fearful looking for of judgment and fiery indignation, which shall devour the adversaries. (Hebrews 10:26-27)

Did you mean to skip over Alma 11:37?

And I say unto you again that he cannot save them in their sins; for I cannot deny his word, and he hath said that no unclean thing can inherit the kingdom of heaven; therefore, how can ye be saved, except ye inherit the kingdom of heaven? Therefore, ye cannot be saved in your sins.


1 I am speaking only of this world, our mortality, and our Heavenly Father's plan for the salvation of His children on this Earth. Scripture teaches that our Heavenly Father has created "worlds without number" (Moses 1:33). None of those other worlds are contemplated here, nor are they at any time in LDS theology. However, people being people, one will find those who feel compelled to speculate about what life and religion might be like on those other creations.

You said, "At the time of Alma, Jehovah had not yet been born. The BoM establishes that Jesus is the Christ, the Eternal God, BoM title page, and at 2 Nephi 26:12. Also, you have Smith in his first vision saying God the Father and God the Son appeared to him. He ask both of them which church to join. "I was answered that I must join none of them because their creeds were an abomination." Then in 1835 Smith started translating the Egyptian hieroglyphics of the BoM and he finished in 1842. Was not Jesus born 2,000 years before this time, and He is the eternal God, a little late don't you think?

@Mr.Bond Forgive me for being blunt - but your study of LDS theology and history is poor. 2 Nephi 26 is a prophecy of the future when Christ visits the Nephites after His resurrection. Joseph Smith's First Vision was in 1820, 1900+ years after Christ's resurrection. The title page was given to Joseph Smith when he began translating, again, 1900+ years after Christ's resurrection. When Zeezrom was speaking in Alma 11, it was ~100 years before Christ's resurrection. Math works out just fine. Are you simply Mormon bashing or are you legitimately trying to understand us?

Oh I understand you alright. Now think for a moment. Since you believe Jesus Christ is eternal God and He incarnated some 2,000 years ago BEFORE the BoM was translated, one has to first "ASSUME" the BoM is true. So JBH, what evidence can you provide proving the BoM is true?

@Mr.Bond That's not what this Stack is about at all. You seem to want to participate in the 1900-year-long shouting match. Nobody here is interested. Think about it... there's no proof the Bible is true, you just assume it is. There's no proof the Qur'an or the Tripitaka or the Veda are true. People assume they are. You and I can argue forever... but if you're not willing to open your heart to my ideas or me to yours, then it's just more of the 1900-year-long shouting match. If you want to learn about us,... (*Continued*)

... you're welcome to ask your questions and learn. If you just want to bash and demand proof, you can take it somewhere else. I assure you, a lifetime of studying the scriptures of my faith and seeking the inspiration of the Holy Ghost, along with the experiences I've enjoyed, have proven to my own satisfaction that I'm where I need to be. Want to know more about that? I'll send you some missionaries to speak with... but here on this Stack, it's just about understanding one another. Go somewhere else to continue the 1900-year-long shouting match.

I might want to clarify Polytheistic point. LDS believe they are monotheistic this answer pt 2 has multiple Q&A on this topic, and LDS sources don't make this claim

Or more clearly from general conference To acknowledge the scriptural evidence that otherwise perfectly united members of the Godhead are nevertheless separate and distinct beings is not to be guilty of polytheism;

I'd say LDS belief is closer to monolatry, but again not an exact match

@depperm That's a great word that I've never heard before. I agree that it's the closest match.
